# Telerik Grid add, update and delete not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik

I'm using mvc c# and Html.Telerik().Grid

I want to add, update and delete on grid. but it doesn't post the data to add, update and delete function.

this is my grid

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid<GownHire.Models.tblstudent>()
        .Name("Grid")
        .DataKeys(dataKeys => dataKeys.Add(c => c.PKStudentID))
        .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert())
        .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding

            .Ajax()                
                .Select("_studentList", "Admin")              
                .Insert("studentInsert", "Admin")                
                .Update("studentUpdate", "Admin")                
                .Delete("studentDelete", "Admin")
        )
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.studentEnterDate);
            columns.Bound(c => c.flage);

            columns.Command(commands =>
            {
                commands.Edit();
                commands.Delete();
            })
                       .Width(180);
        }))
```

this is mu functions

```
    [GridAction(EnableCustomBinding = true)]
    public ActionResult studentUpdate(GridCommand command, tblstudent model)
  {
    // model data is null
    }
```

what is the wrong with my code?

Comment: Your method names are stated under `.Ajax()`. The method names in your controller class must match those names.

Comment: sorry. I forgot to change the function name in my question. still have the same error.

Comment: Have you absolutely verified that your update method doesn't get called by putting a breakpoint at the top of the method?

Comment: update method(studentUpdate) is calling. but model data is null

Comment: Are you using TryUpdateModel? That's how we have our methods coded. http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/telerik-asp-net-mvc-grid-preview-take-2

Answer (score -1):

user1348351: your actionMethod "CeremonyUpdate" is not what you declared on the grid. Change it to "_studentList" for selecting data and it will work